# Magento: connect manager errors / Aitoc extension

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I have a local magento installation to test out new extensions and configurations. Now I try to open the Connect Manager locally, but get a blank screen, and the following errors:

```
PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\x16' (ASCII=22) state=0 in /var/www-vhosts/magento.local/htdocs/app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitsys/Model/Module/License/Light/Performer/Reader.php(36) : eval()'d code(18) : eval()'d code(1395) : eval()'d code on line 1
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www-vhosts/magento.local/htdocs/app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitsys/Model/Module/License/Light/Performer/Reader.php(36) : eval()'d code(18) : eval()'d code(1395) : eval()'d code on line 1
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PEAR_Error::set() in /var/www-vhosts/magento.local/htdocs/downloader/Maged/Pear.php on line 111
```

I see that this has to do with an Aitoc extension or license. What's the best way to fix this error, or disable the extension locally?

---

SOLUTION (thanks to Mcnab)

With freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php you can download the files using the magentoconnect extension key and you can avoid using Magento Connect altogether. This doesn't fix the problem I describe here, but for me it works and is good enough.

Comment: I can't give a specific answer to you - my recommendation would be to try to disable the Aitoc modules through the Aitoc interface in the backend if that is at all possible. I have had disasters before trying to disable modules via System->Config->Advanced or via the xml in app/etc/modules.   I hate those modules, back up first!

Comment: On another note - use this http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php to download the files using the magentoconnect extension key and you can avoid using Magento Connect altogether.

Comment: Thanks! Freegento doesn't fix the problem, but the problem doesn't need to be fixed anymore...

Comment: That's great, at least you worked around it. I hope that's the last error you get from those Aitoc modules! :)

Comment: McNab, if you want you can create an answer and I'll aprove that!

Comment: No probs rxt - cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and paste in the magentoconnect extension key to download a tarball of all the files for your module.

This means you can at least see what has been added to the install and where.  And of course it means you can also look at the code that you are adding prior to it being added to your Magento installation - ie identifying conflicts and downright dodgy code.